# URL link scraper and analyser

Tags: python, console, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I recently wrote a testing tool (called `plink`) for retrieving all the links from a website (and then retreiving links from the linked pages, and so on).

Essentially, the tool is designed to be pointed at a site, and will give you a summary of any broken links etc.

It includes whitelisting/blacklisting and allows you to specify the depth of recursion.

The project also contains unit testing, but I feel these are out-of-scope for the code review.

I'm *fairly* new to the Python ecosystem, having only written small single-file scripts in the past. I'm a .NET developer by day, and am trying to branch out a little. All advice is welcome! Thanks :)

Here's a directory tree if you need it:

```
src
  plink
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    analyser.py
    options.py
    result.py
  tests
    [tests_are_here]
```

`__main__.py` includes the entry point, "splash screen" and argument parsing:

```
import argparse
import pkg_resources
from plink.analyser import Analyser
from plink.options import Options
from termcolor import colored

def print_splash_screen(verbose):
    logo = '''
       _ _       _    
      | (_)     | |   
 _ __ | |_ _ __ | | __
| '_ \| | | '_ \| |/ /
| |_) | | | | | |   < 
| .__/|_|_|_| |_|_|\_\ 
| |                   
|_|                   
    '''
    print(colored(logo, "magenta"))
    if verbose:
        print(colored("plink v" + pkg_resources.get_distribution('plink-url').version, "cyan"))

def initialise(arguments):
    return Options(whitelist=arguments.whitelist, depth=arguments.depth, blacklist=arguments.blacklist, start_url=arguments.start_url, verbose=arguments.verbose)

def main():
    #Retrieve, validate and parse arguments from CLI
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("start_url", type=str, help="Initial URL to analyse")
    parser.add_argument("--whitelist", "-w", help="Domains to analyse. Can only be provided if blacklist is missing", nargs="*")
    parser.add_argument("--blacklist", "-b", help="Domains to skip, Can only be provided if whitelist is missing", nargs="*")
    parser.add_argument("--depth", "-d", type=int, help="Number of analysis cycles", const=3, default=3, nargs="?")
    parser.add_argument("--verbose", "-v", action="store_true", help="Give more output (including potential errors, and a list of individual URL scans)")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    #Both whitelist and blacklist cannot be specified
    if args.whitelist is not None and args.blacklist is not None:
        parser.error("Either provide a whitelist, or a blacklist, you cannot specify both")

    print_splash_screen(args.verbose)

    options = initialise(args)
    a = Analyser(options)
    a.analyse()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`options.py` is a file designed to hold data about the program's config options.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Options():
    whitelist: list[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    blacklist: list[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    depth: int = 3
    start_url: str = ""
    verbose: bool = False
```

`analyser.py` is where the main functionality is housed at the moment:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from plink.result import Result
from termcolor import colored

class Analyser():
    def __init__(self, options):
        self.options = options

    def retrieve_content_by_url(self, url):
        request = requests.get(url)
        content = request.text
        return content

    def retrieve_links_from_html(self, html, base_url):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
        link_tags = soup.find_all('a')
        links = [tag['href'] for tag in link_tags]
        absolute_links = [urljoin(base_url, link) for link in links]
        return absolute_links

    def analyse_url(self, url, depth):
        try:
            content = self.retrieve_content_by_url(url)
            links = self.retrieve_links_from_html(content, url)
            if self.options.verbose:
                print(colored((depth * "  ") + "Success: " + url, "green"))
            return Result(links=links, status="Success")
        except Exception as ex:
            if self.options.verbose:
                print(colored((depth * "  ") + str(ex), "red"))
                print(colored((depth * "  ") + "Fail: " + url, "red"))
            return Result(status="Fail")
    
    def find_domain_from_url(self, url):
        domain = urlparse(url).netloc
        if domain[:4] == "www.":
            return domain[4:]
        return domain

    def compare_domains_from_urls(self, url1, url2):
        formatted_url1 = self.find_domain_from_url(url1)
        formatted_url2 = self.find_domain_from_url(url2)
        return formatted_url1.lower() == formatted_url2.lower()

    def check_whitelist(self, url):
        return any(self.compare_domains_from_urls(url, w) for w in self.options.whitelist)

    def check_blacklist(self, url):
        return not any(self.compare_domains_from_urls(url, w) for w in self.options.blacklist)
    
    def print_summary(self, urls_analysed):
        number_of_successful_urls = sum(1 for url in urls_analysed if url[1] == "Success")
        number_of_failed_urls = len(urls_analysed) - number_of_successful_urls
        print(colored(f"{number_of_successful_urls} successful URLs", "green"))
        print(colored(f"{number_of_failed_urls} failed URLs", "red"))

    def analyse(self):
        use_whitelist = self.options.whitelist is not None
        use_blacklist = self.options.blacklist is not None
        # Define default lists to analyse
        analysed_urls = []
        urls_to_analyse = [self.options.start_url]

        # Each "step" is the next level of depth
        for depth in range(0, self.options.depth):
            urls_in_step = urls_to_analyse[:] # Copy list without reference

            # Each "step" contains a list of urls to analyse
            # This list will be empty by the time the step ends
            for url in urls_in_step:
                if url not in [url_result[0] for url_result in analysed_urls]:
                    # Check the blacklist doesn't contain the url OR the whitelist does contain it
                    if (use_whitelist and self.check_whitelist(url)) \
                    or (use_blacklist and self.check_blacklist(url)) \
                    or (not use_blacklist and not use_whitelist):
                        result = self.analyse_url(url, depth)
                        analysed_urls.append((url, result.status))
                        urls_to_analyse.remove(url)

                        # The URL has been analysed, remove it from this step and add it to the analysed list
                        for url_to_analyse in result.links:
                            if url_to_analyse not in urls_to_analyse:
                                urls_to_analyse.append(url_to_analyse)
        
        self.print_summary(analysed_urls)
```

`result.py` is a dataclass designed to hold information about the results of a single URL scan:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Result():
    links: list[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    status: str = ""
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We're calling `retrieve_links_from_html()` for every resource we retrieve, regardless of its content type.  That surely can't be right.  We should be using a different function for PDF documents, and not attempting to parse most other types.

And it looks like we're attempting to access every link we find, regardless of its scheme.  We probably don't want to be opening `mailto:`, `tel:` or `payto:` links!

Comment: Good point :) I'll scheme checking to the to-do list, thanks!